# Why isn't pyautogui tracking the coordinates of my mouse?

Tags: python

I've tried everything and `pyautogui` isn't tracking my mouse in `pycharm`

I've tried:

```
import pyautogui

print(pyautogui.position())
```

---

```
import pyautogui

while True:
    print(pyautogui.position())
```

---

and I've tried

```
import pyautogui as lms 


getinfo = currentMouseX, currentMouseY = lms.position()
print(getinfo)
```

and nothing is working. Again, I'm using `pycharm` and `python 3` but I don't think that matters.

Comment: what means `nothing is working`? Do you get error when you run in console/terminal? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: your code is working for me - especially with `while`-loop. Maybe problem is only PyCharm. Try code directly in console/terminal (without PyCharm) - `python script.py`

Comment: I do not get an error when i run this code but pycharm just leaves a blank and then right under it, "Process finished with exit code 0." Also, i tried it in command prompt and it said, "import not  recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." I also used the 2nd code but it also just said the same thing.

Comment: in command prompt you should run as `python script.py` - if you try directly as `script.py`  then it may think it is `batch file`. or if you try to run code `import ...` directly i command prompt then it may think it is system command, but system doesn't have command `import` and it may display `import not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: code seems OK and it should run. You could have problem only if you would have all inside function and you forgot to run this function. Is this really all your code? OR maybe you write code in one file but you run different file and this makes problem. Maybe remove all file and start from the beginning - create new file with new name and put only `print("Hello World")`. We can't reproduce your problem so we can't help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
        while True:
            x, y = pyautogui.position()
            positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
            
            print(positionStr, end='')
            time.sleep(0.05)
            print('\b' * len(positionStr), end='', flush=True)
```

Sleep used for printing results otherwise results may show up in 'delay' ( it's not delay its the opposite to fast to show )
also the print formatted in convenient way

Comment: There's nothing wrong with OP's code. Why do you want to change it?

Comment: pyautogui will print cursor positions if sleep used else its not shown , my example insures desired clean output

Comment: @None you should describe this `sleep` in answer (not in comments) because showing only code with sleep doesn't explain it and we can't read in your mind.

Comment: @None why will it not show cursor position? It works fine for me.

Comment: @None the code did not work and just did the same thing i was getting for the other code which was a blank and under the blank "Process finished with exit code 0."

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I just had to re-install pycharm. Thanks for everyone's help though